# BroadcastChannel / MessageEvent timestamp?

Tags: javascript, message, broadcast-channel

BroadcastChannel messages have a timeStamp property. The timeStamp property is a number (previous examples have been 769585.9000000637, 14569.200000027195, 305355.4000000004). You can get your own sense of this by copy/pasting the below code into a your console.

Where does that number come from, what does it mean, and how do I parse it into a useful Date or Time or DateTime?

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('stack')

bc.onmessage = function(ev){
  console.log(ev)
  console.log(ev.data)
  console.log(ev.timeStamp)
}

bc.postMessage('foobar')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inherited from [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp) and I believe it ends up being the time in milliseconds since the BroadcastChannel was created.